# error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token and many others

Tags: c++

Either I am blind or there is not an error. I think it would be probably the first choice. Please help me find a needle in a haystack. This is a part of my list of errors:

```
server.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
server.cpp:64:16: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token
server.cpp:71:14: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token
server.cpp:71:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
server.cpp:71:24: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
server.cpp:72:12: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token
server.cpp:80:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘=’ token
make: *** [server] Error 1
```

and this is a part of my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <signal.h>
#include <dirent.h>

using namespace std;

/* global variables */
// error codes
#define ERR_OK = 0;
#define ERR_PARAMS = 1;
#define ERR_SOCKET = 2;
#define ERR_BIND = 3;
#define ERR_OTHER = 99;

// others
#define LISTEN_BACKLOG 50

/* function prototypes */
void printErr(int EC);
int second(int port);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int pflag = 0;
  string pvalue;
  int port;
  int c;

  opterr = 0;
  while((c = getopt (argc, argv, "p:")) != -1) {
    switch(c) {
      case 'p':
        pflag = 1;
        pvalue.assign(optarg);
      break;
      case '?':
        if(optopt == 'c')
          fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
        else if(isprint (optopt))
          fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
        else
          fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n", optopt);
        return ERR_PARAMS;
      default:
        abort();
    }
  }

  if(pflag == 0) {
    printErr(ERR_PARAMS);
    return ERR_PARAMS;
  }
  printf ("pvalue = %s\n", pvalue.c_str());

  port = atoi(pvalue.c_str());

  second(port);

  return ERR_OK;
}
```

I have many more similar errors in the whole code, so I think there is something like missing collumn od something. Do you see it? I don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define ERR_OK = 0;
#define ERR_PARAMS = 1;
#define ERR_SOCKET = 2;
#define ERR_BIND = 3;
#define ERR_OTHER = 99;
```

should be

```
#define ERR_OK 0
#define ERR_PARAMS 1
#define ERR_SOCKET 2
#define ERR_BIND 3
#define ERR_OTHER 99
```

A macro is not a variable. It does not hold a value. It is a preprocessing feature.

The reason you were having syntax errors popping up everywhere is because `ERR_OK` and the like were being replaced with `= 0;` rather than `0` for example.

Comment: YES! Thanks a lot! I knew it will be something stupid, but for an hour I could not find it. :)

Comment: I think I should erase this topic now, this isn't very helpful question for others. Is it posible?

Comment: That's totally up to you. However, it's usually better to keep the topics so that we can mark future ones like this as duplicates and link back here. In fact, this is probably a duplicate on it's own, as I doubt no one ever asked such a question.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are right that the problem is the symbolic constants

```
#define ERR_OK = 0;
#define ERR_PARAMS = 1;
#define ERR_SOCKET = 2;
#define ERR_BIND = 3;
#define ERR_OTHER = 99;
```

However, in C++ there's a better way to fix these:

```
const int ERR_OK = 0;
const int ERR_PARAMS = 1;
const int ERR_SOCKET = 2;
const int ERR_BIND = 3;
const int ERR_OTHER = 99;
```

Or, C and C++ both allow

```
enum ERROR_CODES {
  ERR_OK,
  ERR_PARAMS,
  ERR_SOCKET,
  ERR_BIND,
  ERR_OTHER = 99
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `#define`s are incorrect, they should look like this, for example:

```
#define ERR_PARAMS 1
```

That is, they should have no `=` and not end with a semi-colon. `#define` is a preprocessor directive. They don't obey the same syntax rules as the rest of C++. In particular, a preprocessor directive is terminated by a new line, rather than by a semi-colon.

```
#define ERR_PARAMS = 1;
```

This is actually defining `ERR_PARAMS` to be `= 1;`. If you then replace `ERR_PARAMS` with `= 1;` in your code, you'll see why some of the errors pop up. For example, consider this line:

```
printErr(ERR_PARAMS);
```

If you replace `ERR_PARAMS` here, you'll get:

```
printErr(= 1;);
```

Well that's certainly not right!

Answer (score 1):

```
#define ERR_OK = 0;
#define ERR_PARAMS = 1;
#define ERR_SOCKET = 2;
#define ERR_BIND = 3;
#define ERR_OTHER = 99;
```

should be

```
#define ERR_OK 0
#define ERR_PARAMS 1
#define ERR_SOCKET 2
#define ERR_BIND 3
#define ERR_OTHER 99
```